# How to check if array has element at index in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to access array at specific index and Typescript says object is possibly undefined even if I check it's not.

```
{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((index) => (
          <div
            className="relative aspect-square w-full max-w-[180px] rounded-md border dark:border-primary-dark"
            key={`image-${index}`}
          >
            {images[index] !== undefined && (
              <Image
                className="rounded-md object-cover"
                fill
                alt=""
                src={URL.createObjectURL(images[index].file)}
              />
            )}
          </div>
 ))}
```

Typescript return error at images[index] - object is possibly undefined (I check it's not above)

I tried to use non-null assertion but eslint says it's forbidden.

Comment: this is a limitation of ts according to [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  Copy `images[index]` to a variable before checking it and using it. See the linked q/a for more info.